WebRTC file record form safari browser mac OS is very large than chrome window OS
Files collected from recordRTC on Safari and Mac OS browser. Since the file size exceeds 100 mb, the video can not be stored in the cloud and database.
Code setting camera resolution
async checkCamera() {
      await navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: true, video: {
            width: { min: 320, ideal: 640, max: 854 },
            height: { min: 180, ideal: 360, max: 480 },
            frameRate: { ideal: 15, max: 20 },
            facingMode: 'user'
          }

Code setting RTC option
options: {
        type: 'video',
        mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus',
        disableLogs: true,
        timeSlice: 1000,
        // auto stop recording if camera stops
        checkForInactiveTracks: true,
      },
      timeForQuest: [300, 300, 300, 300, 300],
      timeLeft: 300,
      popupSixty: false

It may be possible to reduce the file size when recording videos from safari and mac os browsers for record or record file in cloud if file size above form 100 mb.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
